# Vertical text output from an Access query?

Tags: ms-access

When querying an MS-Access database, is there a built-in way to output all the columns in their own labeled row?

I'm looking for something similar to

"Execute Current Statement (Vertical Text Output)"     <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

in MySQL Workbench.

e.g.

```
******************** 1. row *********************
       id: 1
firstname: Bob
 lastname: Loblaw
    email: bob@example.com
******************** 2. row *********************
       id: 2
firstname: Ann
 lastname: Elk
    email: ann@example.com
```

Comment: To what end?  What's your use case?

Comment: To view the data without endless horizontal scrolling

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't a built-in way to do this in Access.